# Удаление символов из си-строки

Tags: c++, строки

Нужно удалить первые 5 символов из строки (строка1). Потом скопировать 1 строку во вторую и заполнить пустые места восклицательными знаками (строка2).
Написал код, всё должно работать, по идее, но не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h> 

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(0, "");
    // получаю строки от пользователя
    char stroka1[20];
    char stroka2[20];

    cout << "Заполните символами первую строку -> ";
    std::cin.getline(stroka1, 20);
    cout << "Заполните символами вторую строку -> ";
    std::cin.getline(stroka2, 20);

    // ищу знак "*" или "/" в первой строке и удаляю его. Добавляю восклицательных знаков в конец строки
    int i = 0;

    for (int q = 0; stroka1[q]; ++q) {
        if (q < 5) {
            stroka1[q] = ' ';
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (; stroka1[i]; ++i) { 
        stroka1[i] = '!';
    }

    // вывожу содержимое этих строк
    std::cout << "Содержимое первой строки: " << stroka1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Содержимое второй строки: " << stroka2 << std::endl;

    // копирую первую строку во вторую
    strcat(stroka2, stroka1);

    std::cout << "Содержимое второй (результирующей) строки: " << stroka2 << std::endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: с помощью " "  - вы не удаляете символ

Comment: Блин, было же уже?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for (int q = 0; stroka1[q]; ++q) {
    if (q < 5) {
        stroka1[q] = ' ';
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Это не удаление символа, а перезапись пробелом.

Или

```
memmove(stroka1,stroka1+5,strlen(stroka1+5)+1);
```

или можно ручками...

```
char * to = stroka1, *from = stroka1+5;
while(*to++ = *from++);
```

Код не компилировал, так, для общего представления идеи..

Comment: `stroka1[q] && q<5`